# Extracting multiple numbers from string variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, oracle10g

I have a varchar variable with contents like this: '123,12,7654321,9998...'.
I work in Oracle 10gR2.
How can I achieve the following output format?:

```
------
123
12
7654321
9998
...
------
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using `connect`:

```
with str as (select '123,12,7654321,9998' as val from dual)
select cast(regexp_substr(val,'[^,]+', 1, level) as int)
from str
connect by cast(regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, level) as int) is not null;
```

I'll admit that I adapted it from this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement).  What you are trying to do is commonly put into a function called "split".

Comment: Hm, thank you, Gordon Linoff! I'll try to apply your advice..Unfortunately, I don't know about connect by cast...It's time for learning!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE,'text()') VALS 
FROM XMLTABLE('123,12,7654321,9998');
```

or

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE VALS FROM XMLTABLE('123,12,7654321,9998');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/* Formatted on 1/30/2013 1:24:07 PM (QP5 v5.227.12220.39724) */
WITH val AS (SELECT '123,12,7654321,9998' txt FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt,
              '[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+',
              1,
              lvl)
  FROM (SELECT txt,
           LEVEL lvl
      FROM val
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=   LENGTH (txt)
                - LENGTH (REPLACE (txt,
                           ','))
                + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Swapna Mohan! It works too!) Can you advise any books about regular expression or all I need is reading docs.oracle.com?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know of any books on regular expressions. http://docs.oracle.com/ is all i used for that and ofcourse code from projects that I worked on.